# Int vs Integer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, int

Does anyone know what the difference is between these two types?

The docs only refer to `Int` but Xcode 6 auto complete only gives me `Integer` when I type.  I started using `Integer` when porting code only to find that you have to cast between the two types.

For instance the following code gives the error *Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments*.

```
var number1 : Int = 5
var number2 : Integer = 10
number1 + number2
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An `Int` is the type whilst an `Integer` is a protocol it implements.

You should be using `Int` in declarations, i.e:

```
var num: Int = 5
```

which is also the type that's inferred for integer literals when a type isn't specified, i.e:

```
var num = 5
```