# My first swift hello world application, build error when trying access a class

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

So this is my hello world application with swift. Also not used to XCode. So, might be a silly mistake here.

I just have one class Deck.swift

```
class Deck {

    let decks : Integer = 0

    init () {
       decks = 1
    }

    init (amountOfDecks : Integer){
       decks = amountOfDecks
    }

    func getAmountOfCards() -> Integer {
        return 0
    }

}
```

Then I'm trying to run a unit test that look like this

```
import XCTest
import helloWorldv2

class helloWorldv2Tests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testDeckConstructor() {
        var deck = Deck(amountOfDecks: 2)
        XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
    }

    func testExample() {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
    }

}
```

If I comment out the line **var deck = Deck(amountOfDecks: 2)** then it builds fine. If that line is included I get build failed.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Because there is no Constructer with one argument. init is not consider as constructer in swift.

Comment: Can you post the build error?

Comment: It worked when I build it on a virtual Iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify deck param you have to declare it like this

```
var decks : Int = 0
```

If you put let your variable is read only after first assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst @jaumard is correct in saying that it is **var** rather than **let** that you should be using, you should use "Int" as the type, not "Integer" (which is a protocol, not a type). You get away with it because both are superfluous because of type inference...

```
var decks = 0
```

is quite sufficient, or

```
var decks: Int = 0
```

if you want to be verbose.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053432/int-vs-integer-in-swift).

Answer (score 0):

No need to turn your `let` constant into a `var`.
Simply don't provide a default value when declaring it.

```
let decks : Int
```

Your `= 0` already initializes your constant, and than you're trying to change it in init, which is not allowed for constants.